# Assign new Column based off values in separate Column

Tags: python, numpy, assign

I am trying to find a more efficient way to assign values to a `Column` based off values in a separate `Column`. For the `df` below, I want to assign a `0` to weekdays and `1` to weekends.

This is my attempt:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = ({             
   'Day' : ['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday'],                                                                                                                                                 
    })

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df['Group'] = np.where(df['Day'] == 'Monday', 0, 1)
df['Group'] = np.where(df['Day'] == 'Tuesday', 0, 1)
df['Group'] = np.where(df['Day'] == 'Wednesday', 0, 1)
df['Group'] = np.where(df['Day'] == 'Thursday', 0, 1)
df['Group'] = np.where(df['Day'] == 'Friday', 0, 1)
df['Group'] = np.where(df['Day'] == 'Saturday', 1, 0)
df['Group'] = np.where(df['Day'] == 'Sunday', 1, 0)

Output:

         Day  Group
0     Monday      0
1    Tuesday      0
2  Wednesday      0
3   Thursday      0
4     Friday      0
5   Saturday      0
6     Sunday      1

Intended Output:

         Day  Group
0     Monday      0
1    Tuesday      0
2  Wednesday      0
3   Thursday      0
4     Friday      0
5   Saturday      1
6     Sunday      1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you do `df['Group'] = np.where(...)` you are setting the values of the `Group` column from the beginning. So, in your series of statements, the only one that really counts is the last one:

```py
df['Group'] = np.where(df['Day'] == 'Sunday', 1, 0)
```

To work around this, you can set all values of the `Group` column at once:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = ({             
   'Day' : ['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday'],                                                                                                                                                 
    })

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['Group'] = np.where(df['Day'].isin(['Saturday', 'Sunday']), 1, 0)

Output:

         Day  Group
0     Monday      0
1    Tuesday      0
2  Wednesday      0
3   Thursday      0
4     Friday      0
5   Saturday      1
6     Sunday      1
```

Comment: Cheers @araraonline

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way using df.apply

```
import pandas as pd

DAYVALUE = {'Monday':0, 'Tuesday':0, 'Wednesday':0, 'Thursday':0, 'Friday':0, 'Saturday':1, 'Sunday':1}

>>>df
         Day
0     Monday
1    Tuesday
2  Wednesday
3   Thursday
4     Friday
5   Saturday
6     Sunday

df['Group'] = df.loc[:,'Day'].apply(lambda x: DAYVALUE[x])

>>>df
         Day  Group
0     Monday      0
1    Tuesday      0
2  Wednesday      0
3   Thursday      0
4     Friday      0
5   Saturday      1
6     Sunday      1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also check this way

```
d = pd.DataFrame({             
   'Day' : ['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday'],                                                                                                                                                 
    })


group = []

  for i, row in d.iterrows():
    if row['Day'] == 'Saturday' or row['Day'] == 'Sunday':
        group.append(0)
    else:
        group.append(1)
d['group'] =group
```